# Newfoundland Geospatial data source

Tags: data-request, geospatial, canada, download

I am looking for a source of geospatial data for Newfoundland, Canada comparable to Land Information Ontario (LIO) in Ontario. We are in need of mapping at scales 1:20000 (metric) and larger scales and the available CanVec federal datasets are too course for our purposes (~1:50K). Ideally, I would like to obtain LiDAR or equivalent topography as well as ortho-imagery, hydrology, transportation and other basemap data.

Google search doesn't seem to reveal any useful sources: https://opendata.gov.nl.ca/ (confusing site with no extensive data catalog/download options)

https://gis.geosurv.gov.nl.ca/ (links to very basic interactive maps and links to federal data)

Comment: Newfoundland has a population less than 0.5 million compared with Ontario's 13.5 million, so expecting data of a similar quality seems...optimistic.

Comment: Opendata.gov.nl.ca is possibly the worst government data portal I've ever seen. It feels like there might be useful data on there somewhere, but you might as well close your eyes and click randomly as use the search function. I did find this website, with a shapefile of Public Water Supply Areas with Intakes, wellheads, boundaries: https://www.mae.gov.nl.ca/waterres/gis/gis.html. Then there's canadiangis.com, but I can't tell if that's a real website or just a shell.

Comment: this old question popped up on the active questions page today, maybe it will help: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/1128/bathymetric-contour-data-for-north-america and also try this one: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69756/where-can-i-get-detailed-bathymetry-data-for-ontario/70461